# PHP / Laravel and Jenkins

Tags: php, laravel, jenkins

I'm Integrating Laravel and Jenkins, and it seems to be working.

The only problem I have is that all my tests are used with base Url : http://localhost.

So All my tests fails because it says:

```
 http://**localhost**/path/to/uri] failed. Received status code [500].
```

So, all the test fails because I guess I don't know

- Where should I define what should be the http://localhost to be the baseUrl I want.
- What should I put here, or where should I configure it... I could log ssh to my Jenkins machine and curl my url to see what's the response to see if it is responding well, but I'm quite unsure how should this work...

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Open *TestCase.php* which is inside *test* folder. There you should have `protected $baseUrl` which should be your application URL.

Comment: But I'm a little confused about what should be my $baseUrl... When running in my dev server, I have no problem because I know my root URL, but in Jenkins, I don't know at what URL should it be accesible???

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro well I don't know too. It should be the name of your domain, the way you access the website.

Comment: I can access Jenkins site with http://52.204.32.244/jenkins/ but then, I can only access Jobs. I will keep searching !!!

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro well that is as much as I can help you. I hope you find some solution for this, good luck.

Comment: Yep, I will tell you if I find a solution!